# unbound frontier_exploration goal

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, frontier-exploration, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently using Ubuntu ARM 14.04 with ROS Indigo ARM.
I am using a actionlib client to send a goal to the explore_server of the frontier_exploration package in order to make my robot ( TurtleBot 2 ) do an unbound exploration of its environment. The problem i have is that, after beginning the exploration it works OK for some time before stopping moving. When it stop moving, it in fact receive goals at his current position, thus cycling though the same patern :

gmapping_demo.launch window

```
Got new plan
Goal reached
Got new plan
Goal reached
```

Anyone have an idea why it behave like that ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209485/unbound-frontier_exploration-goal/) by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is likely due to goals being generated in the footprint of the robot. frontier_exploration's costmap should be clearing the footprint automatically, however I've found this to be inconsistent. I am working on adding a footprint-goal-filter type of mechanism to an upcoming version of frontier_exploration.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on 2015-05-19**:
Thanks a lot for your works, i am looking forward to seeing the new version of your package which helped me a lot !